# How to onmouseover enlarge a table cell to the size of its background image?

Tags: html, css

I have an image gallery set up where the pictures are partially shown in each cell (as a preview) as the cell background. When the mouse moves over the cell, the cell expands to the size of the full picture. I was wondering if there was a way to automatically resize the cell to the image dimensions instead of manually imputing the full dimensions as the height and width of the cell on mouse over. I've already tried replacing height='200px' to height=auto or height=100% but neither seem to work.

Here's an example of the code:

```
<table cellpadding="0" border="0">  
        <tr>
            <td width="275px" height="200px" onmouseover="width='400px'; height='268px'" style="background-repeat:no-repeat" 
            class="fx" onmouseleave="width='275px'; height='200px'" align="center" background="images/kitchen/1.jpg"></td>

            <td width="275px" height="200px" onmouseover="width='400px'; height='268px'" style="background-repeat:no-repeat" 
            class="fx" onmouseleave="width='275px'; height='200px'" align="center" background="images/kitchen/2.jpg"></td>

            <td width="275px" height="200px" onmouseover="width='400px'; height='268px'" style="background-repeat:no-repeat" 
            class="fx" onmouseleave="width='275px'; height='200px'" align="center" background="images/kitchen/3.jpg"></td>
       </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You have 3 td's (cells) in one row. If you increase the height of one cell, the height of the other cells on that row will also be increased. This will affect the background-image's. You can create a default style that shows the background with background-position: center center; And a :hover style to increase the cell size. You can use the background-size: contain; to fit a hovered cell.

Comment: Playing with this code, uncovered an interesting effect to me. I'll paste my test code in an answer for the purpose of playing with it. (you have to supply your own images).

Answer (score 5):

You may want to take a look or a  try at transform :scale(); (no bumping effects)

```css
table {
  table-layout:fixed;
  margin:auto;
  width:550px;
  }
td {
  width:275px;
  height:200px;
  background:url(http://dummyimage.com/400x268) center no-repeat;
  transition:0.25s;
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 2px;
  }
td:hover {
  background-size:  100% 100%;
  transform:scale(1.4545,1.34);
  transform-origin:center;
  }
body {
  text-align:center;
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
<img  src="http://dummyimage.com/400x268" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider using javascript to do this.

If so you can change the `onmouseover` and `onmouseleave` events to...

`onmouseover="function1(this);"` and `onmouseleave="function2(this);"`

then in javascript use this to change the width and height properties of the elements...

```
function1(elem)
{
    var elementID = elem.id;
    document.getElementById(elementID).style.width = '400px';
    document.getElementById(elementID).style.height = '268px';
}
function2(elem)
{
    var elementID = elem.id;
    document.getElementById(elementID).style.width = '275px';
    document.getElementById(elementID).style.height = '200px';
}
```

Note that you will have to give each of the td elements an unique id.

So with the ids and functions your html tds would look like this...

```
<td id="cell1" width="275px" height="200px" onmouseover="function1(this);" style="background-repeat: no-repeat;" 
class="fx" onmouseleave="function2(this);" align="center" background="images/kitchen/1.jpg"></td>
```

To get the id of the element in javascript you can use...

```
var elementID = elem.id;
```

I hope this helps, let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

The `onmouseover` and `onmouseleave` attributes should contain script, not style. If you want to use styles to do the job, create css styles `fx` and `fx:hover`, and move all styling from tag attributes into the class.

```
<style>
    .fx {
      border: 0;
      background-repeat:no-repeat;
      background-position: center;
      width: 125px;
      height: 125px;
    }
    .fx:hover {
      width: 250px;
      height: 250px;
    }
</style>
```

If you don't want to hardcode image sizes and if you don't want to see whole row and column expanded on hover, you need to dig into javascript and other thin matters with layers of divs.

Comment: I'm ok with the rest of the row  expanding on hover as well

Answer (score 1):

Interesting effect: (I would use images larger than the sizes used in the css)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Css and Html Test</title>
<style>
table tr td {
    width: 275px;
    height: 200px;

    text-align: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
table tr td:hover {
    width: 400px;
    height: 268px;
    background-size: contain;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<table cellpadding="0" border="0">  
        <tr>
            <td class="fx" background="image1.jpg"></td>
            <td class="fx" background="image2.jpg"></td>
            <td class="fx" background="image3.jpg"></td>
       </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But look you're still manually imputing the full image dimensions. The point of this is to be able to use images with different dimensions and still have the code work properly (show the full image on mouse hover)

Comment: You'll probably need to use a script to get the individual dimensions of each image. Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190069/check-uploaded-images-dimensions